# Gamemaker Studio 2 html5 game sfx influence background music volume

Tags: game-maker, sound

When I run my game in html5 the game sound effects for shooting makes the background music less audible. It is like the volume of the bg music goes down. 
And when shooting is done it goes up again.

When I run my game in test everything is fine. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was caused by many bullets that were all fired at once with each their own soundeffect. 
All these sound effects together caused the problem. Now I only play the sound once and the problem is gone.